# pygameで画像が開けません

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))
pygame.display.set_caption("主人公を動かす")

player=pygame.image.load("annpannmann.png").convert_alpha()

while(1):
    pygame.display.update()

    screen.blit(player,playe.get_rect())

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==quit:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
```

annpannmann.pngを読み込みたいのですが、どう変えても

```
error: Couldn't open annpannmann.png
```

というエラー文がでてしまいます。拡張子もあっているはずです。どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

ありがちなのがプログラム実行時のカレントフォルダにそのファイルが無い状況です。
確認してみてください。

[pygameでのpygame.image.load()による画像描画の方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/166777)
[pygameで画像を表示しようとするとエラーになる](https://teratail.com/questions/145649)

こちらはPython2.x系で普通に動く記事
[イメージを描画する](http://aidiary.hatenablog.com/entry/20080505/1275697567)

`images`等のサブフォルダにファイルがある場合の処理
[Python - error: couldn't open .png file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42335678/9014308)

> ```
> import os
>
> current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) # Where your .py file is located
> resource_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'resources') # The resource folder path
> image_path = os.path.join(resource_path, 'images') # The image folder path
>
> player_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'dude.png'))
> ```