# pygame画像が読み込めない

Tags: python, 画像, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
import sys

def main():
    (w,h)=(400,400)
    (x,y)=(200,200)
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h),0,32)
    screen=pygame.display.get_surface()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Test")

    bg= pygame.image.load("C:\prog\python\pygame\\bg.png").convert_alpha
    rect_bg=bg.get_rect()

    player=pygame.image.load("C:\prog\python\pygame\player.png").convert_alpha
    rect_player=player.get_rect()
    rect_player.center=(x,y)

    while(1):
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(30)
        screen.fill((0,20,0,0))
        screen.blit(bg,rect_bg)
        screen.blit(player,rect_player)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

main()
```

と入力すると

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cdbff3e182ab> in <module>
     34                     sys.exit()
     35 
---> 36 main()
     37 

<ipython-input-17-cdbff3e182ab> in main()
     11     pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Test")
     12 
---> 13     bg= pygame.image.load("C:\prog\python\pygame\\bg.png").convert_alpha
     14     rect_bg=bg.get_rect()
     15 

error: Couldn't open C:\prog\python\pygame\bg.png
```

とエラー文が出てきてしまい、bg.png が読み込めません。
プログラムと同じファイルに画像ファイルがあること確認しました。どうすれば改善しますか？

Comment: [前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65797/19110)、[前々回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65793/19110)と同じような内容のご質問に見えるのですが、何か差分はありますでしょうか？　同じ内容の質問であれば回答も一箇所にまとめるためにひとつの質問を編集する形にしていただきたいです。またもし差分があればそれが分かりやすくなるような形にまとめていただけると回答する側としてはありがたいです。ご検討よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ちなみに画像ファイルをフルパス名で指定しているので、「プログラムと同じフォルダに画像ファイルがあること確認」しても意味がないですよ。指定したフルパス名の場所に画像ファイルが存在する必要があります。 それからエラーメッセージからするとjupyter notebookとかの環境みたいですが、それは一旦止めて管理者モードで起動したWindowsのコマンドプロンプトから実行してみてはどうでしょう？ 何か変わるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルがあって、でもバックスラッシュ文字をエスケープシーケンスと解釈している都合上ファイルパスがくるって見える現象に悩まされるくらいなら下記のどれかに書き換えちゃうと良いっす。

- ディレクトリ区切り記号をスラッシュ文字にする (Unix Style Path)
  `pygame.image.load("c:/prog/python/pygame/bg.png")`
- RAW 文字列とする
  `pygame.image.load(R"c:\prog\python\pygame\bg.png")`
- `os.path.join` でパスを作る
  `pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:", "prog", "python", "pygame", "bg.png"))`

これでも読めないなら https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load に解説がある通り `png` ファイルが未サポートなのでしょう。